# Why show "django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError" in Django App & can't run the server

Tags: python, django

I got "django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:" in my Django App.

Here is My settings.py code

```
'rangefilter',
'csp',
'jazzmin',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'sales',
```

And here is my admin.py code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Sale_Data
from import_export.admin import ExportActionMixin
from rangefilter.filters import DateRangeFilter, DateTimeRangeFilter

class Sale_Record(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =("CustomerName","CustomerPhone","Date", "Item", "Qty_Memory", "Qty_HDD", "Total_Qty", "Prices", "SalePerson")
    search_fields =("CustomerName", "CustomerPhone")
    list_filter = ('Date', DateRangeFilter)

admin.site.register(Sale_Data, Sale_Record)
```

Error show like this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Z0S.png)

Comment: I know how to fix it replace  list_filter = ('Date', DateRangeFilter) to list_filter = (('Date', DateRangeFilter),).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *list_filter* takes a tuple, where the first element is a field name and the second element is a class inheriting from
> django.contrib.admin.FieldListFilter

```
class Sale_Record(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =("CustomerName","CustomerPhone","Date", "Item", "Qty_Memory", "Qty_HDD", "Total_Qty", "Prices", "SalePerson")
    search_fields =("CustomerName", "CustomerPhone")
    list_filter = (
        ('Date', DateRangeFilter),
    )
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)